# Set Transaction Type to RETURN conditionally in maximo

Tags: maximo

In Work order tracking application in actuals tab materials section when user clicks on New row by default the transaction type = ISSUE . I would like to change this by default to RETURN and remove issue from the look up (I was able to remove ISSUE from the lookup). This requirement should only work  for PM type work orders. Hence I tried to write an automation script on MATUSETRANS.ISSUETYPE attribute launch point however it throws null pointer expection which trying to perform setValue. I tried using 2L,7L and 11L however it doesn't work.

```
if(onadd) ==True:
  mbo.setValue("ISSUETYPE",'RETURN')
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: A stack trace for the null pointer exception would be helpful.

Comment: I got the same error. That's odd, looks like the mbo variable isn't bound. I'll need to look under the hood...

Comment: @JPTremblay I was able to solve this, not sure if I can post an answer by myself . Let me try

Answer (score 1):

We basically need to trigger the code on a field that sets after ISSUETYPE is set using the out of the box code so I tried on field like currencycode or condrate  (attribute launch point) and it works like charm. You will have to use 7L though to the existing code.

Comment: That's what I would have tried too. Looks fine to bypass action and validation since that's what IBM seems to be doing in the `Matusetrans.add` method.